# Unable to change the container's static IP in the docker swarm overlay network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

recently,

I have one container which has joined the swarm overlay network,

sometimes, I will change the static IP for a number of reasons,

but not sure why the IPv4Address from the `docker network inspect` will

still show the old IP address, but not the new one,

For example:

step 1. Running a container by
`docker run -itd -h kafka_1 --name kafka_1 kafka:latest`

step 2. Assign a network interface for joining the overlay network 
`docker network connect --ip 172.20.0.110 test-overlay-net kafka_1`

step 3. Attach to kafka container and the change ip by
`ifconfig eth1 172.20.0.111 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.20.255.255`

step 4. Logout the container, and check the inspecting info by
`docker network inspect test-overlay-net`

Step 5. and realize the IP address is still the old one even the ip is already changed successfully in the container.

`"Containers": {
   "df1de7d9809f3e84857ef19db10f7c50d3d65153dcd47f3b22af6ed3a5ab1b41": {
       "Name": "kafka_1",
       "EndpointID": "37fe6b03b87435f897780826992a6e1f9b491444738c10de6c7c56aea3edb71d",
       "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:6f",
       "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.110/16",
       "IPv6Address": ""
            },`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

currently, I just find the way for workaround by using `docker network disconnect -f test-overlay-net kafka_1`, and then re-connect again by the `docker network connect --ip`

much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like docker reads the ip from it's internal management, not directly from the container's network namespace, so docker is not aware of your IP change.
It may happen that docker assigns the address you set inside your container to a newly attached one resulting in an address conflict when you don't explicitly specify an IP. There may also occur problems with overlay packet routing.
In sum I would not recommend changing ip settings inside a container.
What is your use case?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
my use case is about the HA implementation,
here is a service(container) which will create on the overlay network on each node(VM*3), but executed by Active-Passive mode(VM-1 Running, VM-2 Standby, VM-3 Standby), and once VM-1 is gone, then VM-2 will boot up the service and then leverage the container IP which used by VM-1's container previously.

Comment: but, finally, just like you mentioned above,
it seems doesn't allow user to do that thing,
so, I just force demote the dead node in the overlay network by the other swarm manager nodes when some nodes(VM) are gone.